# how to interpret the jacoco.xml file?

Tags: xml, parsing, code-coverage, jacoco

I am using the **JACOCO** tool in Maven project. It creates code coverage XML file **"jacoco.xml"**. As I'm going to parse this xml I need to know the meaning of some attributes in the xml file. xml contains following elements:

```
    <sourcefile name="Ops.java">
        <line nr="3" mi="0" ci="3" mb="0" cb="0"/>
        <line nr="5" mi="0" ci="4" mb="0" cb="0"/>
        <line nr="11" mi="0" ci="5" mb="2" cb="2"/>
        <line nr="12" mi="0" ci="2" mb="0" cb="0"/>
        <line nr="14" mi="8" ci="0" mb="0" cb="0"/>
        <line nr="15" mi="2" ci="0" mb="0" cb="0"/>
        <counter type="INSTRUCTION" missed="10" covered="14"/>
        <counter type="BRANCH" missed="2" covered="2"/>
        <counter type="LINE" missed="2" covered="4"/>
        <counter type="COMPLEXITY" missed="2" covered="3"/>
        <counter type="METHOD" missed="0" covered="3"/>
        <counter type="CLASS" missed="0" covered="1"/>
    </sourcefile>
```

variable "nr" seems to mean line number. what are the meanings of the variables **"mi", "ci", "mb" and "cb"**?

And here is the code coverage shown in generated html output.

[image: generated html output]

Comment: mi = missed instructions
ci = covered instructions
mb = missed branches
cb = covered branches

ps: https://github.com/codecov/example-java

Comment: @StevePeak You should just turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`mi = missed instructions (statements)
ci = covered instructions (statements)
mb = missed branches
cb = covered branches`

- When `mb` or `cb` is greater then 0 the line is a branch.
- When `mb` and `cb` are `0` the line is a statement.
- `cb / (mb+cb)` (line 11) is `2/4` partial hit (hence yellow)
- When not a branch and `mi == 0` the line is hit (hence green in line 5)

Thank you!

> **Bonus:** Upload these reports to Codecov https://github.com/codecov/example-java

Comment: You could get all the definitions in report.xml from [report.dtd](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/coverage/report.dtd).